# How to sort date column in datatable jquery api?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using datatable jquery api. I have a table which contains a date column, of  which, data are in text format i.e. `August 2nd, 2016`. Here, the column is sorted in alphabetical order not according to the dates. What should I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, convert the dates using following line of code.

```
$timeStamp = strtotime('August 2nd, 2016');
```

Then, in the date column in your table, use this line of code.

```
<td data-order="<?php echo $timeStamp; ?>">August 2nd, 2016</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this in aoColumns;

```
        {
            sTitle: "Date", mData: "StartTime", mRender: function (data) {
                return data == null ? "" : '<span style="display:none;">' + new Date(data).getTime() + '</span>' + new Date(data).toLocaleString();
            }
        },
```